# How to dynamically change ConverterParameter (or any) property of a MultiBinding (or any other) resource at runtime?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, converters

i'm new to wpf and xaml. i find solutions of most of the problems (in other languages) by searching here n there or googling around but this one made me crazy. i searched a lot on google and browsed many forums, but it seems that this time i met with a real challenge!

I have following code in Window.Resources:

```
<my:NameConverter x:Key="NameConverter"/>

<MultiBinding x:Key="CustomerFullNameBinding" 
              Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}"
              ConverterParameter="LastNameFirst">
     <Binding Path="FirstName"  />
     <Binding Path="MiddleName" />
     <Binding Path="LastName" />
</MultiBinding>
```

The **NameConverter** class returns full name by combining individual parts of the name. The return value is based on value of **ConverterParameter** which can be one of the following: *FirstNameFirst, LastNameFirst, OnlyFirstName, OnlyLastName, Initials* (there are a few more; but for simplicity, let's not consider them)

This code works fine. I use following to get the result:

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource CustomerFullNameBinding}"/>
```

However, the problem is that if i use the resource **CustomerFullNameBinding** 20 times in my code (like shown abovw) all of them would show the name in ONE particular format. (i.e. Here in the declaration of CustomerFullNameBinding i have set *ConverterParameter="LastNameFirst"* so all 20 references will show name in that way only.)

**Now my question is can i make it more "generalized" so that the i can set the value of *ConverterParameter* dynamically?** i.e. i can have multiple textblocks that can display full name in different formats. I know it is possible if we create multiple resources like follows:

```
 <MultiBinding x:Key="CustomerFullNameBinding_FirstNameFirst" 
               Converter="..." ConverterParameter="FirstNameFirst">
      ......
 </MultiBinding>
 <MultiBinding x:Key="CustomerFullNameBinding_LastNameFirst" 
               Converter="..." ConverterParameter="LastNameFirst">
      ......
 </MultiBinding>
 <MultiBinding x:Key="CustomerFullNameBinding_OnlyFirstName" 
               Converter="..." ConverterParameter="OnlyFirstName">
      ......
 </MultiBinding>

 ... and so on ...
```

But i dont want that, 'coz it'll really make my code too bulky, and most importantly it'll void concept of reusability of resources!

Please suggest me any possible solution. 
Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I got the original idea from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752275.aspx). The similar working example can be found msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771336.aspx.

Tags: wpf xaml staticresource dynamicresource binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to change the display mode used on each instance, I think I would have done it something like this:

- Create a `UserControl` with 3 `TextBlock`s for displaying the 3 parts of the name.
- Add properties to the above for the parts of the name to be targets of binding.
- Add a property for the mode in which to display (*FirstNameFirst*, *LastNameFirst*, etc.)

The above requires a binding for each of the pieces of the name, so one way to simplify that would be to make a single property on the `UserControl` of a type `NameData` declared as a struct with `First`, `Middle`, and `Last` properties. Then you could still use a single `MultiBinding` to that property. The difference would be that your `NameConverter` would take the 3 pieces and return a new `NameData` struct instead of a formatted string.

```
<NameTextBlock NameData="{DynamicResource CustomerFullNameBinding}" NameDisplayMode="LastNameFirst" />

<NameTextBlock NameData="{DynamicResource CustomerFullNameBinding}" NameDisplayMode="FirstNameFirst" />

<NameTextBlock NameData="{DynamicResource CustomerFullNameBinding}" NameDisplayMode="Initials" />

<!-- and so on... -->
```

The idea is to decouple the formatting from the data.

The part that tripped things up was declaring one `MultiBinding` as a resource. Usually, there would be a `MultiBinding` on each `TextBlock` you are binding to so that you can change the `ConverterParameter` for each case.

**Edit:** I know you wanted to be able to change `ConverterParameter`, but that's not really possible due to the 1 instance of `MultiBinding` and `ConverterParameter` being a plain property rather than a `DependencyProperty`, which would be required to be the target of a `DynamicResource` or `Binding`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.

You are true. ConverterParameter is a plain property, not a DependencyProperty. Actually I'm new to WPF and sometimes I forget basic concepts too! Having a user control bound to a dynamic resource that returns a structure instead of a string is really a great idea. I've not really tried it, but I'm sure it's gonna work!! Thank you once again!!!